# Regex, match with different patterns at once

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a giant string with this format:

```
5 [105.68 - 143.759] some text
6 [143.759 - 173.88] some text
7 [173.88 - 201.839] some text
...
```

I want to match:

1. Numbers including the dot between `[` and  `-`, this is the regex: `/(?<=\[).*?(?=\ )/`
2. Numbers including the dot between  `-` and `]`, this is the regex: `/(?<=\-\ ).*?(?=\])/`
3. All text after `]` , for this I use this regex: `/(?<=\]\ ).*/`

So for example for the first line the matches will be: `105.68`, `143.759` and `some text`

This works but I want to know if is possible to match those three patterns at once, I tried concatenating the different patterns with `|` but it didn't work with this:

```
const re = /(?<=\[).*?(?=\ )|(?<=\-\ ).*?(?=\])|(?<=\-\ ).*?(?=\])/
const regex = RegExp(re, 'gm')
regex.exec("7 [173.88 - 201.839] some text")
```

Output 1st time calling exec: Array [ "201.839" ]
Output 2nd time calling exec: Array [ "173.88" ]
Output 3rd time calling exec: null

Is there a way to get all this (and the actual text, not null) in a single call?

Comment: Do you wish to confirm the numbers have a correct format? For example, do you wish to reject `'1.2.3'`, `01.23'`, `'.123'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `match()` with three capture groups:

```js
var input = "5 [105.68 - 143.759] some text";
var matches = input.match(/\[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*-\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\]\s+(.*)/);
console.log("1st num: " + matches[1]);
console.log("2nd num: " + matches[2]);
console.log("text:    " + matches[3]);
```

If you need to apply this to a multiline string, then you could split the string by space and then apply the above to each line.

Comment: how can I also match the text `some text`?

Comment: Sorry...missed that requirement.  Use 3 capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

If the regular expression

```
\[(0.\d+|[1-9]\d*\.\d+)\D+(0.\d+|[1-9]\d*\.\d+)\] *(.*)
```

matches the string the three capture groups will hold the strings of interest.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T3o2fs/1)

I realize that a Javascript solution is wanted but would like to point out that if the regex engine had been one that supported [subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) (PCRE and others) one can save some characters and possibly avoid copy-paste errors by writing

```
\[(0.\d+|[1-9]\d*\.\d+)\D+((?1))\] *(.*)
```

Here `(?1)` in effect copies the tokens used to construct capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ImJJrL/1)

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```js
    const regex = /(\d+\.\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+\.\d+)\]\s*(.*)/;
    const str = "7 [173.88 - 201.839] some text";
    const match = str.match(regex);
    
    if (match) {
      console.log("First number:", match[1]); //173.88
      console.log("Second number:", match[2]); // 201.839
      console.log("Text:", match[3]); // some text
    } else {
      console.log("No match found.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /(\d+\.\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+\.\d+)\]\s*(.*)/;
const str = "7 [173.88 - 201.839] some text";
const match = str.match(regex);

console.log("First number:", match[1]);
console.log("Second number:", match[2]);
console.log("Text:", match[3]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).